# Natural logarithm power notation

Tags: notation, logarithms

I am trying to understand how to use Dirichlet's test for convergence and saw an example [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/dirichlet-s-test-for-convergence-examples-1) (example 2).

> Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2n}n^2}{e^n\,n!}\frac{1}{\ln^2n}$ converges.

Could someone please explain to me what $\ln^2n$ means? Does it mean $\ln(\ln(n))$, $(\ln(n))^2$ or something else entirely?

PS: I'm a newbie in both mathematical analysis and math SE. I spent quite a bit of effort in typing this so I hope that there aren't any glaring mistakes in the formatting. Please let me know if there are any!

Comment: I guess it's $(\ln n)^2$; it's a very ambiguous notation indeed.

Comment: @egreg I'm hoping that having the context of the question will help. Thanks for helping me edit!

Comment: 1. Use Stirling approximation 2. Combine $4^{n}$ and $n^{n}$ 3. Combine $n^{2}$ and $(\ln n)^2$ 4. Find some sequence which larger than that and converges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Stirling's formula: With the $n$th term being $A_n,$ show that $A_{n+1}/A_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty,$ which is more than enough for convergence, as even the weaker result $\exists r\in (0,1)\;\exists m\;(n>m\implies$ $ |A_{n+1}|\leq r|A_n|)$ guarantees absolute convergence by comparison with the geometric series $\sum_n r^n.$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

1. Using Stirling :
   $$yoursum =  \sum {\frac{4^{n}n^{2}}{n^{n}(\ln n)^{2}}}$$
2. $$\frac{4^n}{n^n} \le \frac{1}{n^2} $$ for some big $n$

Now find upper bound of second part.